# telerik:RadWindow: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: telerik, radwindow

I'm using telerik:RadWindow to display RadEditor. At the very first time popup worked fine. But in the second time it gives `TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.` javascript error. This only happens in Chrome browser.

I have added timeout to fire the radwindow.show() function. Then it works fine. Any idea to fix this issue?

Markup:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="winSection" runat="server" Width="800px" Modal="true" VisibleStatusbar="false" style="z-index: 2999;"
        VisibleTitlebar="true" Behaviors="Move" AutoSize="true" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="popupModalTitle" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="ltrlTitle" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="sectionPopupTitle">
                <label for="txtTitle">
                    <asp:Label Text="Title"
                        runat="server" />
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" Width="415" CssClass="txtTitlePopup" MaxLength="100" />
            </div>
            <telerik:RadEditor runat="server" ID="radEditor" Height="550px" Width="850" EditModes="All" ContentFilters="DefaultFilters" ExternalDialogsPath="~/Controls/RadEditorDialogs/"
                OnClientCommandExecuted="OnClientCommandExecuted">
                <ImageManager ViewPaths="~/Pages/Uploads/" UploadPaths="~/Pages/Uploads/" DeletePaths="~/Pages/Uploads/" />
                <Tools>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="AddInternalLink" Text="Add Internal Link" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="ImageManager" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="LinkManager" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Unlink" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="AjaxSpellCheck" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="SelectAll" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Cut" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Copy" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Paste" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="PasteStrip" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Undo" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Redo" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Superscript" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Subscript" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertParagraph" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertGroupbox" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertHorizontalRule" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="FormatBlock" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="FontName" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="RealFontSize" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Bold" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Italic" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Underline" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="StrikeThrough" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyLeft" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyCenter" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyRight" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyFull" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="JustifyNone" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Indent" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="Outdent" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertOrderedList" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertUnorderedList" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="ToggleTableBorder" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="ForeColor" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="BackColor" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="FormatStripper" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                    <telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertSymbol" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="InsertTable" />
                        <telerik:EditorSeparator />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="ConvertToLower" />
                        <telerik:EditorTool Name="ConvertToUpper" />
                    </telerik:EditorToolGroup>
                </Tools>
            </telerik:RadEditor>
            <div id="Div2" class="popupModalButtons center" runat="server">
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="OK" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="saveSectionBtnClick(); return false;" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btn" OnClientClick="closeRadWindowBtnClick(); return false;" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" ToolTip="Close" CssClass="btnClose" OnClientClick="closeRadWindowBtnClick(); return false;" />
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

To popup this window i'm using following javascript code:

```
function openRadWindow() {
      var radwindow = $find(radWindowClientID);
      adwindow.show();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe if you could provide some code that would help us help you.

Comment: @Veselin code snippet added to the question.

Comment: Cool. Now, what does it mean "the second time it does not work"? You open the window the first time, that's fine, how do you open it the second time? Do you first click OK, Cancel or anything else? What happens when you click those buttons - include their event handlers too.

Comment: Do you call the onParentNodeChanged() RadEditor method: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-troubleshooting-radeditor-in-radwindow.html?
Also, make sure you use the correct ID, something like this: $find("<%=winSection.ClientID%>"),show();